# YouTube API Error, Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

```
When I try to connect with YouTube API (by node.js) this error show up:
```

```
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
                                                           ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        at authorize (D:\Node.js\yt-api\server.js:37:56)
        at processClientSecrets (D:\Node.js\yt-api\server.js:24:3)
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

```
    var express = require('express');
    var server = express();
    var fs = require('fs')
    var readline = require('readline');
    var {google} = require('googleapis');
    var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

    server.use(express.static('public'));

    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
    var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'];
    var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
        process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
    var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';

    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
      }
      // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
      authorize(JSON.parse(content), getChannel);
    });

    /**
     * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
     * given callback function.
     *
     * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
     * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
     */
    function authorize(credentials, callback) {
      var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
      var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
      var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
      var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
      fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
          oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
          callback(oauth2Client);
        }
      });
    }

    /**
     * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
     * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
     * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
     *     client.
     */
    function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
      var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
      });
      console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
      var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });
      rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
            return;
          }
          oauth2Client.credentials = token;
          storeToken(token);
          callback(oauth2Client);
        });
      });
    }

    /**
     * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
     *
     * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
     */
    function storeToken(token) {
      try {
        fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
          throw err;
        }
      }
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
    }

    /**
     * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    function getChannel(auth) {
      var service = google.youtube('v3');
      service.channels.list({
        auth: auth,
        part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }
        var channels = response.data.items;
        if (channels.length == 0) {
          console.log('No channel found.');
        } else {
          console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                      'it has %s views.',
                      channels[0].id,
                      channels[0].snippet.title,
                      channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
        }
      });
    }


    var port = process.env.port || 4001;

    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    })
```

How to fixed it up ? Its some wrong with oAuth2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `client_secret.json` file is missing a key for `"redirect_uris"`

See below a sample file:

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    "client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback"],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```